# how to limit resources to a shared ubuntu 10.04

Tags: server, 10.04, security, users, acl

The title might not be explanatory enough but I couldn't find any better way to formulate it. I will be running a server for office use. It will host applications on tomcat. 2 differents people would be deploying the application they are working on (office policy, all developers should be familiar with it).

I know there is `ACL` module at HDD level but I think it would be an overkill to do that for this purpose. Beside its usage is not so clear to me as I would want to use it in a a way where I could list allowed actions like listed below , allowed for an user or group as opposed to listing the users/groups who are allowed for a particular resource/script etc.

I would like to create a group which would be giving a particular set of privileges such as:

- create a folder in /opt/tomcat*/webapps `* there could be different instances`
- start/stop/restart a particular tomcat servive `example service tomcat-1 start`
- start/stop/reload/restart apache2 `for reverse proxy purpose`
- edit /etc/apache2/sites-available `for reverse    proxy purpose`
- activate/deactivate sites using a2ensite or a2dissite

How can I achieve that in Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Thanks to bacon, I got some going. But I looks like there are few kinks. I created the users user1, user2, user3 and added them to the group `deployers`. All tomcat instances created with `tomcat-user` are inside `/opt/tomcat7/` so I changed the user ownership of the folder to `tomcat7` and the group owner ship to `deployers` and `chmod to 775`. I have made a copy of `/etc/init.d/tomcat7` to suit each of my instances and added them to `update-rc.d`.
with visudo I have created `DEPLOYERS` Cmnd_Alias and configured it as shown below:

```
Cmnd_Alias    DEPLOYERS= /etc/init.d/tomcat_instance_1,/etc/init.d/tomcat_instance_2,/sbin/sh,/usr/bin/service
%deployers    ALL=(ALL) DEPLOYERS
```

I have logged in with user1 credentials and I still can't run `/etc/init.d/tomcat_instance_1 start` because it says "You need root privileges ...".

I thought the Command Alias would take care of that. Can anyone shed the light thanks?

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice tutorial for [adding users to a group](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/) If you give that groups rights to the folder than that should solve your first problem and your fourth problem.

I would solve the rights for stating and stopping Apache and Tomcat by giving limited sudo rights for specific commands. This can be done using `sudo visudo` to edit the /etc/sudoers file. A nice tutorial can be [found here.](http://www.garron.me/en/linux/visudo-command-sudoers-file-sudo-default-editor.html)

I'm not sure about your fifth question but I'm guessing one of the above solutions apply's

Comment: pretty interesting, thank you for the post, I will digest and revert.

Comment: I have tried couple of things regarding the links you shared. Seems am still not good to go. Kindly check in your free time. Thanks

Comment: @black sensei Sorry for the delay, 2 things 1)dit you prepend sudo to your command. I think your still supposed to. 2) your probably supposed to add the exact command: /etc/init.d/tomcat_instance_1 *start*